# How to upload multiple file in AEM using HTML code

Tags: java, html, aem

I am trying to upload multiple files using simple HTML code in AEM. In the front end, it shows that multiple has been upload. But in a request, only one file is available. 
Below is my sample HTML Code

```
<form name="formname"  method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="form.html" style="display: block;">
<input multiple="multiple" type="file" id="field-supportingFiles" name="supportingFiles" class="input-file" accept=".pdf, .doc, .docx, .rtf, .txt, .html, .jpeg, .png">

  <button type="submit" >Submit  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/1201244

Comment: Can you check what is the actual request that is sent from the browser to AEM? As a side note, is this functionality expected to work in publish environments as well?